# Reading and translating a table from a word document to properly structured dataframe using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have a word document with a table that looks like below :

[image: sample table]

I want to translate this using python to something like this:

[image: result table]

My current python script produces an output that looks like below:

[image: current result]

My current script is:

```
data=[]
for row in table.rows:
  row_data=[]
  for cell in row.cells:
      for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
          for run in paragraph.run:
               #do some manipulation with run.text and produce result
      row_data.append(result)
  data.append(row_data)
```